# Good practice related to empty arrays and notices

Tags: php, notice

I started developing something more complex that what I did before and I want to do it "by the book" and I've read that notices should be avoided, even if they don't affect the usability.

So I have a function that checks the URL and splits it into multiple parts. I then use it to generate the pages, but I get a notice on the frontpage as there aren't enough parts.

Here's some code to see what I'm talking about:

```
$slug = getRightURL();
```

In `getRightURL()` I have:

```
$curURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URL = explode('/', $curURL);
return $URL[2];
```

So when the url is just `http://example.com/` the function throws a notice;

I was thinking about adding this:

```
if(count($URL) > 1) return $URL[1];
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `isset`/`empty` are usually used to check for stuff like this.

Comment: You can do `return empty($URL[2]) ? null : $URL[2];`

Comment: ternary with a default value is what I would suggest. `return isset($URL[2])  ?$URL[2] : $defaultValue;`. Default value can also be passed in or just defined in the function.

Comment: @CBroe I don't think I can use them here, because the array could have a single element and I request the 2nd.

Comment: @imtheman This looks better than my solution.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That's much shorter, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just counting doesn't always do the trick as PHP arrays aren't actually arrays (something indexed from 0 to length-1) but maps where you can have all kind of not sequenced strings and numbers as index.

To find out if a particular index exists, use isset().

```
if(isset($URL[2])) {
    return $URL[2];
}
else {
    return '';
}
```

You could also shorten this with the ternary operator like so:

```
return (isset($URL[2]) ? $URL[2] : '');
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest way to get rid of notices and I've implemented your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer without seeing the exact specifications of what your `getRightURL()` should return, but if it is the last section of the parsed url, you can use:

```
$URL = explode('/', $curURL);
return last($URL);
```

And you should look into [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse your url. That will give you more reliable results than parsing-by-exploding:

```
$URL = parse_url($curURL);
return $URL['path'];
```

Comment: I didn't know about `parse_url`, but it doesn't seem any better from me than `REQUEST_URI`. My urls are either as `/something`, /something/something-else`, or `/something/something-else/some-more/`.

Comment: @Alex But you use it on `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: It returns the entire `REQUEST_URI`. Did I do something wrong? `var_dump(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Comment: @Alex It returns an array, you need to get the right element like in my answer. And you can explode the `path` part and use the first part of my answer if you need to parse the path itself.

Comment: Yes, it returns an array with only `path` in it. Unfortunately I can't use `last()`, because something else might be added after my URL, like tracking IDs and it would break my script.

Comment: @Alex No, the tracking ID would likely be in the query variables, the path will be clean (depending on your url structure of course).

Answer (score 1):

Before using `explode()` on the requested uri, try cleaning up the string a bit and adding a bit of error checking. Both `trim()` and `isset()` come to mind.

```
// If the uri were /controller/view or /controller/view/...

$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");

// trim with a character mask of "/" will clean up your uri leaving
// controller/view

$uri = explode("/", $uri);

// As a side note, calling explode on an empty string will return an array
// containing an index (key) of 1 and a value of "" (empty string). This is
// important as you don't have to implicitly check if $uri is an array with
// is_array() or fear a warning appearing when passing explode an empty string
// (i.e. explode("/", "") results in array([1] => ))

// Check that you did need explode and that the requested index exists...
if(isset($uri[2])) {
    ...
}
```

**References:**
`trim()`
`isset()`